# Shop sends Mail with order cancellation

Tags: order

We currently have a problem with our shop sending cancellations to our customers after they have successfully created and payed an order.

They place an order, pay and everything works fine. The status of the order is correct as well.
But after a few minutes our system creates an cancellation document and sends it via mail to our customer.

Anyone an idea whats the problem here?

Thanks a lot in advance.
All the best

Comment: This is WooCommerce? Can you check your "Hold stock (minutes)" setting on the inventory admin page - is that just a few minutes, i.e. is this what's cancelling the order? If it is, I'd guess something isn't right with the payment status somehow.

Comment: (But you might do better asking in the WooCommerce support forums, not here sorry.)